# Edit in grace period should allow un-downvote, too

Tags: feature-request, voting

This question: [open pop up window on map marker from outside map canvas after click an anchor tag in drupal 7 using gmap, location](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/127250/16495) was pretty bad when I downvoted it. A bit more than a single line. It was edited later. Apparently edit happened inside the grace period. So now there is not-that-bad question I would probably leave alone, without downvote. But I can't un-downvote it, due to lack of entry in question's revision history.

I think un-downvote should be possible even if edit happened inside grace period. Do you share that view?