# Can I do non-edits to remove misplaced votes?

Tags: support, editing, voting

Generally, I do very careful when placing down/up votes on a POST. If I misplace down/up votes on posts, I can't retract my vote once grace period ends.

This happens in this case also: [Edit in grace period should allow un-downvote, too](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3057/25879)

In such cases, Can I do non-edits (as my Edits to any question or answer are applied immediately) on posts to retract my votes?

Is it valid behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. All edits should be edits you would be willing to approve, if suggested by low-rep user. True, it leaves us in a bit of void, with no valid thing to do, and doing nothing being invalid on it's own. So think about constructive things you could try:

1. Style and grammar edits
2. [Narrowing images for readability](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/127327/revisions)
3. Tag edits - invalid use of [modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules) is very popular, for example
4. Making question's title a real question

And probably many more. Last thing you can do is to comment to post's author, explaining how you misplaced downvote and promising to undownvote as soon as his post will get changed with new informations. Authors are not so restricted by edit rules.